# How can I solve these errors when doing 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When i type in gnome-terminal, this command (in my Ubuntu 18.04):

> sudo dpkg --configure -a

i get these error messages

> Setting up nfs-common (1:1.3.4-2.1ubuntu5.2) ... debconf: DbDriver
>   "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process:
>   Resource temporarily unavailable dpkg: error processing package
>   nfs-common (--configure):  installed nfs-common package
>   post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
>   Setting up cryptsetup (2:2.0.2-1ubuntu1.1) ... debconf: DbDriver
>   "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process:
>   Resource temporarily unavailable dpkg: error processing package
>   cryptsetup (--configure):  installed cryptsetup package
>   post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1 dpkg:
>   dependency problems prevent configuration of libguestfs0:amd64: 
>   libguestfs0:amd64 depends on cryptsetup; however:   Package cryptsetup
>   is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package libguestfs0:amd64 (--configure): 
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
>   prevent configuration of nfs-kernel-server:  nfs-kernel-server depends
>   on nfs-common (= 1:1.3.4-2.1ubuntu5.2); however:   Package nfs-common
>   is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package nfs-kernel-server (--configure): 
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
>   prevent configuration of libguestfs-reiserfs:amd64: 
>   libguestfs-reiserfs:amd64 depends on libguestfs0 (=
>   1:1.36.13-1ubuntu3.3); however:   Package libguestfs0:amd64 is not
>   configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package libguestfs-reiserfs:amd64
>   (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg:
>   dependency problems prevent configuration of libguestfs-perl: 
>   libguestfs-perl depends on libguestfs0 (= 1:1.36.13-1ubuntu3.3);
>   however:   Package libguestfs0:amd64 is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package libguestfs-perl (--configure): 
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Setting up mdadm
>   (4.1~rc1-3~ubuntu18.04.2) ... debconf: DbDriver "config":
>   /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource
>   temporarily unavailable dpkg: error processing package mdadm
>   (--configure):  installed mdadm package post-installation script
>   subprocess returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency problems
>   prevent configuration of libguestfs-hfsplus:amd64: 
>   libguestfs-hfsplus:amd64 depends on libguestfs0 (=
>   1:1.36.13-1ubuntu3.3); however:   Package libguestfs0:amd64 is not
>   configured yet. dpkg: error processing package
>   libguestfs-hfsplus:amd64 (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving
>   unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
>   libguestfs-tools:  libguestfs-tools depends on libguestfs0 (=
>   1:1.36.13-1ubuntu3.3); however:   Package libguestfs0:amd64 is not
>   configured yet.  libguestfs-tools depends on libguestfs-perl (=
>   1:1.36.13-1ubuntu3.3); however:   Package libguestfs-perl is not
>   configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package libguestfs-tools (--configure): 
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
>   prevent configuration of libguestfs-xfs:amd64:  libguestfs-xfs:amd64
>   depends on libguestfs0 (= 1:1.36.13-1ubuntu3.3); however:   Package
>   libguestfs0:amd64 is not configured yet. dpkg: error processing
>   package libguestfs-xfs:amd64 (--configure):  dependency problems -
>   leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while processing: 
>   nfs-common  cryptsetup  libguestfs0:amd64  nfs-kernel-server 
>   libguestfs-reiserfs:amd64  libguestfs-perl  mdadm 
>   libguestfs-hfsplus:amd64  libguestfs-tools  libguestfs-xfs:amd64

How can I fix this software bug?

Answer (score 1):

I do:

```
apt purge lvm2
```

then

```
apt install lvm2
```

Now I can update and install